# Size availability In tenant admin site collection list - SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online

One of our tenant shows below storage figures  ( 42.88 TB available of 49.24 TB)

Can someone please help me understand what these storage figures mean?

is this total of all site collections? i.e

> Sharepoint Site collection (one with /sites) + Personal sites
>   (/personal , One Drive For business) + Office 365 video site (/Portal)
>   + Office 365 group sites (/teams)

or its just sharepoint site collections and One drive for business, groups sites are calculated separately ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on you screenshot, it display the total storage of all site collections. Not included personal site and one drive.

Refer to the articles:

[SharePoint Online Limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits)

[Manage site collection storage limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-storage-limits)